# Cant Play Video ( .mp4) uploaded from iPhone on Android

Tags: android

Actually i made one application for iphone and android device.. and in that video feature is available so video uploaded by iphone device,video (mp4) is cant played in android device so please any body help me

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    // Set progressbar message
    pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    // Show progressbar
    pDialog.show();

    try {
        // Start the MediaController
        MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                PlayVideoViewFromURLActivity.this);
        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(mVideoView);

        // Get the URL from String VideoURL

        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(vidUrl); // vidUrl is url of video which on server 

        mVideoView.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mVideoView.requestFocus();
    mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        // Close the progress bar and play the video
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            mVideoView.start();
        }
    });
    mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
            finish();
        }
    });
```

full Logcat error :

```
08-13 09:45:10.062: D/MediaPlayer(1929): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side

08-13 09:45:11.770: E/MediaPlayer(1929): error (1, -2147483648)

08-13 09:45:11.790: E/MediaPlayer(1929): Error (1,-2147483648)

08-13 09:45:11.790: D/VideoView(1929): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

Comment: What is the `vidUrl` that is used?

Comment: http://54.187.229.126/jobpop/userVideos/michael123_20140807163642.mp4 this is url

Comment: i got this in my logcat : 08-13 09:45:10.054: W/EGL_emulation(1929): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-13 09:45:10.058: W/EGL_emulation(1929): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-13 09:45:10.062: D/MediaPlayer(1929): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
08-13 09:45:11.770: E/MediaPlayer(1929): error (1, -2147483648)
08-13 09:45:11.790: E/MediaPlayer(1929): Error (1,-2147483648)
08-13 09:45:11.790: D/VideoView(1929): Error: 1,-2147483648
08-13 09:45:11.802: W/EGL_emulation(1929): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

Comment: @Vaishali http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865836/mediaplayer-couldnt-open-file-on-client-side-error-38-0-and-more refer this link please

Comment: @vaishali VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
       myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(SrcPath));
       myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
       myVideoView.requestFocus();
       myVideoView.start();

Comment: @vaishali check above code then to play it.

Comment: @pratik You are copy pasting the code from her question itself. She has implemented the same there.

Comment: @ pratik ,, its not played same error i got

Comment: @vaishali then I think may be there is the problem with your url, domain rtpc not finding it properly.

Comment: @Vaishali Are you playing it on a emulator or device ? If on emulator, then try it on device as it might work there or use GenyMotion emulator. It has better OpenGL support

Comment: @ Alok Nair i had try it also in Moto g and Nexus 5 but still video does not played

Comment: @vaishali if in device it will not work then there may be some issue with the url dear

Comment: but url is correct because i had tried it in browser also and in browser video is playing perfectly ... you may also try it .. i had post url also

Comment: @vaishali now its the issue of RTSP dear, visit this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620049/how-to-play-video-from-url

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976238/couldt-open-file-on-client-side

Comment: @ pratik .. am sorry to say but last link was for Youtube video url.. so your answer is different than my question

Comment: @vaishali ok then sorry, carry on with other solutions, people here can give you reerence things, then you have to search and implement code.

Comment: @Vaishali check alternate solution i have provided below as answer. That code is working on my phone and emulator. But not working with your link, so I think its some issue with the video url.

Comment: @Vaishali Is this a local server URL or Live?

Comment: @ Alok no yar.. its not working 
url is live @  PiYusH GuPtA

Comment: @Vaishali Check this. http://www.itcuties.com/android/play-video/ u r doing wrog

Comment: this video is uploaded from iphon device .. so now is it possible to play ?

Comment: @  PiYusH GuPtA : i had try it also but it cant played still :(

Comment: @Vaishali it may have something to do the way video is encoded. SO do go through http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: @vaishali is it working or not still?

Comment: @vaishali hellow, there?

Comment: @pratik its not working..

Comment: @vaishali ooppsss where were you now a days?

Comment: @Vaishali how are you?

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternative approach for streaming video using the MediaPlayer class,like we use it in creating a music player. You can stream media, including video, to a MediaPlayer object using a surface view. For example, you could use the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class TestAct extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnPreparedListener
{

private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private SurfaceHolder vidHolder;
private SurfaceView vidSurface;
String vidAddress = "https://archive.org/download/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    vidSurface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfView);
    vidHolder = vidSurface.getHolder();
    vidHolder.addCallback(this);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0)
{
    try
    {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDisplay(vidHolder);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(vidAddress);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
{
    mediaPlayer.start();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
{
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
{
}
```

}

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @Vaishali Implementing a streaming media player might help you. http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/29/android-videomusic-player-sample-from-local-disk-as-well-as-remote-urls/

Comment: @Vaishali Also check this solution http://jan.newmarch.name/android/StreamingAudio.html

Comment: @Vaishali Issue is with your url. It is not being played on VLC or GPlayer Android App.

Comment: in VLC i try it .. but in that i can hear voice of vioce but cant able to see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59246/discussion-between-alok-nair-and-vaishali).

Comment: Actually i made one application for iphone and android device.. and in that video feature is available so video uploaded by iphone device is cant played in android device so please me

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: i want to play video in android device.. which is uploaded by iphone users... will it be possible ?

Comment: It depends on how the video and audio streams are compressed in the QuickTime file. If they're the standard H.264 and AAC, you should be able to just change the extension to .mp4 and play it that way. But if it's some weird compression format, it may just be impossible to play without QuickTime

Comment: Then you can play them on Android. I don't see any issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59699/discussion-between-alok-and-vaishali).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59726/discussion-between-vaishali-and-alok).

Answer (score 1):

**Issue:**

It is issue about conflict of encoding-decoding between the video and the device's platform support.

**Solution:**

I would insist to use [Vitamio](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/) library to play the videos in android.
It is pretty simple to use and reliable also.

**Example:**

You can add it to your xml file like `VideoView`,

```
   <io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView
    android:id="@+id/surface_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

You can easily control the player,

```
public class VideoViewDemo extends Activity {

/**
 * TODO: Set the path variable to a streaming video URL or a local media file
 * path.
 */
private String path = "";
private VideoView mVideoView;
private EditText mEditText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    if (!LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this))
        return;
    setContentView(R.layout.videoview);
    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.url);
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
    if (path == "") {
        // Tell the user to provide a media file URL/path.
        Toast.makeText(VideoViewDemo.this, "Please edit VideoViewDemo Activity, and set path" + " variable to your media file URL/path", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    } else {
        /*
         * Alternatively,for streaming media you can use
         * mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(URLstring));
         */
        mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        mVideoView.requestFocus();

        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                // optional need Vitamio 4.0
                mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
            }
        });
    }

}

public void startPlay(View view) {
    String url = mEditText.getText().toString();
    path = url;
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(url)) {
        mVideoView.setVideoPath(url);
    }
}

public void openVideo(View View) {
  mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
}

}
```

**Reference:**

[VideoViewDemo](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/blob/master/vitamio-sample/src/io/vov/vitamio/demo/VideoViewDemo.java)

I hope it will be helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you for reply @ Mehul Joisar .. but still it was not plyed

Comment: Mehul joisar 
i used same code its working my case but there is problem android videoview orientation got changed

Comment: @PrvN: you should check meta data of the video which provides orientation information about it. according to that orientation info, you should rotate and play the video.

Comment: @Mehul Thanks for reply,
 im trying to play video from url ,how to find metadata of video from ulr

Comment: @PrvN: If you want to support old versions then have a look at [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever) otherwise Android has introduced [METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_ROTATION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_ROTATION) from JellyBean

Comment: @PrvN: If you have no concern about rotation degree, then you may try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487063/detect-orientation-of-a-recorded-video-in-android) one easily for portrait and landscape

Answer (score 1):

[Can't Play video in android uploded from iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23627873/cant-play-video-in-android-uploded-from-iphone)

Why mp4 does not play in 4 steps:

1. download you vidView URL to PC with 'ffmpeg'
2. $ffmpeg -i $downloadFileName
3. inspect details of reported codecs
4. compare those reported codecs to what [android media supports](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Note: very likely that #2 will report codecs not listed at #4

Comment: Thanks for reply but video download is not in project`s feature .. i have to buffer it and play

Answer (score 0):

Although the video is .mp4, the video is compressed on iOS in a way that the native android media player cannot play/decode.

I ran into this exact problem OP had when developing for cross platform. An easy alternative is using VLC for Android, which is open source and built upon FFMPEG and utilizes SurfaceViews.

To do this, include the below in your build.grade file:

```
compile "de.mrmaffen:vlc-android-sdk:1.0.3"
```

For example, you can then make a new activity for the Video, and in the onCreate, do the following:

```
mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.player_surface);
mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();

mSurfaceFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.player_surface_frame);
mMediaUrl = getIntent().getExtras().getString("videoUrl");

try {
    mLibVLC = LibVLC.getInstance();
    mLibVLC.setAout(mLibVLC.AOUT_AUDIOTRACK);
    mLibVLC.setVout(mLibVLC.VOUT_ANDROID_SURFACE);
    mLibVLC.setHardwareAcceleration(LibVLC.HW_ACCELERATION_FULL);
    mLibVLC.eventVideoPlayerActivityCreated(Boolean.TRUE);

    mLibVLC.init(getApplicationContext());
} catch (LibVlcException e){
    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
}

mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(mSurfaceCallback);
mSurface = mSurfaceHolder.getSurface();

mLibVLC.attachSurface(mSurface, VideoVLCActivity.this);
mLibVLC.playMRL(mMediaUrl);
```

Lots of info can be found here for troubleshooting:
[VLC for Android VideoLAN Forums](https://forum.videolan.org/viewforum.php?f=35)

There is a more detailed example [here](https://bitbucket.org/edwardcw/libvlc-android-sample), although it uses a different version of libvlc.LibVLC and contains different methods, but it will give you a good idea of what steps are needed to add controls, set the proper size, aspect ratio, orientation etc.

Comment: Hello, I am trying to use vlc in my xamarin.android project but the screen the video show in pixeled and grey screen for first 2 sec do you have any Idea 
I ask new question here, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55357741/using-vlc-player-in-xamarin-android-project