# Using vlc player in xamarin.android project

Tags: android, xamarin.android, libvlc, vlc-android, libvlcsharp

use LibVLCSharp in my project cause the video pixeled and grey screen

I tried to add file-caching=1500 to media player with no success and you can see my code below

```
          this.VideoPath = extras.GetString(INTENT_KEY_PARAM_VIDEO_PATH);
          Core.Initialize();
          _libVLC = new LibVLC();
          _mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(_libVLC);
          _videoView.MediaPlayer = _mediaPlayer;
          var mediaUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(this.VideoPath);
          var m = new Media(_libVLC, mediaUri.ToString(), FromType.FromPath);
          var configuration = new MediaConfiguration();
          configuration.EnableHardwareDecoding();


          m.AddOption(":fullscreen");
          m.AddOption(":codec=avcodec");
          m.AddOption(configuration);
          m.AddOption(":file-caching=1500");
          _mediaPlayer.Media = m;
          _videoView.MediaPlayer.Play(m);
```

Comment: Remove `m.AddOption(":codec=avcodec");`

Comment: Share logs and your media file if possible.

Comment: Remove :codec=avcodec
cause the video show grey screen from first opening

Comment: Remove `EnableHardwareDecoding`, color glitches are usually hardware related. Share your device and media file

Comment: media file any type of videos, my device samsung J6, huawii , I tried to remove hardwaredecoding same thing, actually I have a recycler view and each cell contains video file when video cell click I am trying to play video it's work fine for first call no grey screen no lake if i go back to my recycler view and select any other video even same video grey screen come back

Comment: I am testing your code with a simple demo but in my project, _videoView.MediaPlayer = _mediaPlayer;  shows error: 'VideoView' does not contain a definition for 'MediaPlayer' ...

Comment: Share your **full** code